# Given an array of 2n elements of which n are similar and n are different

Tags: algorithm

Given an array of 2n elements of which n elements are same and the remaining n elements are all different. Write a C program to find out the value which is present n times in the array

I thought in the following way-
compare a[i] and a[i+1] and
compare a[i] and a[i+2]
and return element

this will run in O(n) time..can anyone give better solution?

I was going through some solutions where it is saying like this-

> 1. Declare two variables a) count variable to keep track of count of majority element.
> 2. Majority element.
> 3. Do a for loop and repeat following steps 4-6 until end of array is reached.
> 4. if current array element equals majority element, increment count
> 5. else, if count is 0, update majority element with current array element and increment count.
> 6. else if count is not 0 then decrement count.
> 7. Do another for loop and count the number of occurrences of majority element in the array, if it's half the array size then we have found the majority element, else there's no majority element.

Comment: I think your solution is good enough since it only requires at most half a pass of the array.

Comment: Er, you didn't finish describing your algorithm. But if the run-time is O(n) as you claim, then that you can't get a better Big-O. You have to go through at least O(n) of the input.

Comment: 1. Declare two variables a) count variable to keep track of count of majority element.
2. Majority element.
3. Do a for loop and repeat following steps 4-6 until end of array is reached.
4. if current array element equals majority element, increment count
5. else, if count is 0, update majority element with current array element and increment count.
6. else if count is not 0 then decrement count.
7. Do another for loop and count the number of occurrences of majority element in the array, if it's half the array size then we have found the majority element, else there's no majority element.

Comment: it's *similar* to the majority element problem, you cannot use that algorithm.

Comment: The majority algorithm requires a proper majority, i.e. n+1 from 2n. Just n is not enough for the majority algorithm to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the majority element algorithm as a basis for an O(n) solution with O(1) space.

You need space for one stored element. Pick the first element and store it, if the next element is the same as the stored one, you finished. If not, restart the algorithm from the next step. If you don't find the element after the end of this, it means that the element are ordered in pairs like (a,b),(a,c),(a,d) or (b,a),(a,c),(a,d),(e,a).. Compare the first four elements and you have found the duplicate.

Since elements can be in arbitrary order, whichever first n/2 elements you check it's possible that they are all different. So there is no solution which is bettern than O(n).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with at most two passes and O(1) space by using linear time majority vote algorithm (http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~moore/best-ideas/mjrty/index.html)

Pick the first element and scan the array to decide whether this is the repeating element (scanning half of the remaining array will be enough). If the element is the repeating element, then we are done; if not then apply the linear time majority vote algorithm in the remaning array.

The reason that we are checking the first element is that linear time majority vote only works if the element repeats more than half of number of elements in the array.